# How can I trigger the useEffect() hook with a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code, that loads a random user from an API.
On load, it shows the first name of the fetched user.

Now I want to fetch a new user when clicking the 'Generate user' button, but it's not triggering the `useEffect`.

I thought I could trigger a refresh by passing the `generate` var to the dependency array in the `useEffect`, but it's not working. Should I make `generate` part of the state? That seems counter-intuitive for a simple toggle.

Any help / tips appreciated!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Async = () => {

    let generate = false;
    const [user, setUser] = useState({name: ''});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setUser({...user, ['name']: data.results[0].name.first}))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, [generate]);
    
    function newUser()
    {
        generate = !generate;
    }

    return <>
        <button onClick={newUser}>Generate user</button>
        <div>User {user.name}</div>
    </>;

};
```

Comment: I think `generate` has to be a state. Then you use `setGenerate(true)` and then the `useEffect` should be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move `generate` into a React state that is toggled and triggers a rerender, but it would be better to just abstract the `fetch` call into a callback that is called by the `button` element's `onClick` handler. Call the function once in a mounting `useEffect` hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Async = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: '' });

  const generate = () => {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setUser(user => ({
        ...user,
        name: data.results[0].name.first
      })))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  };

  // Call once when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    generate();
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={generate}>Generate user</button>
      <div>User {user.name}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your Generate With State as Below...

```
export default function App() {

const [user, setUser] = useState({name: ''});
const [generate,setGenerate] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {

    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setUser({...user, ['name']: data.results[0].name.first}))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}, [generate]);

function newUser()
{
    setGenerate(!generate)
}

return <>
    <button onClick={newUser}>Generate user</button>
    <div>User {user.name}</div>
</>;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

## Move your request outside or into a reusable function

```
const reqData = () => {
  // return fetch req
}

const Comp = () => {
  useEffec(() => {
    reqData(); // assign it or whatever you need
  }, [])

  const handleClick = useCallback(reqData);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleCallback}>Generate user</button>
      <div>User {user.name}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is just psudo code, you will have to set up arguments etc to get it to work, but this will allow you to make more calls per click while also having the content access to the initial load call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling api in useEffect you can call it inside a function

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Async = () => {

    let generate = false;
    const [user, setUser] = useState({name: ''});

    useEffect(() => {
        newUser()
    }, []);
    function newUser()
    {
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setUser({...user, ['name']: data.results[0].name.first}))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }

    return <>
        <button onClick={newUser}>Generate user</button>
        <div>User {user.name}</div>
    </>;

};
```

And if you want to go with your code only then put genrate as state like

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Async = () => {

    let [generate, setGenerate] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState({name: ''});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setUser({...user, ['name']: data.results[0].name.first}))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, [generate]);
    
    function newUser()
    {
        setGenerate(!generate)
    }

    return <>
        <button onClick={newUser}>Generate user</button>
        <div>User {user.name}</div>
    </>;

};
```